# how to send redux store to the client when routing in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I am new to nextjs and I am unable to keep the dispatched state on the new built page after routing. Please how do we keep the state.

Basically I have a sidebar I am trying to keep the state of the active button.
I tried using the `getInitialProps` to get url queries and `useEffect` to dispacth an action on load but the redux store is still empty.

useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        var index;
        if (product_id === 'lime') index = 0
        if(product_id === 'travetine') index = 1
        // console.log(entry, index)
        entryClickButton({           // the action I am trying to dispatch however its not happening 
            type: entry,
            newEntries: entry === 'new-entries' ? index : undefined,
            soldEntries: entry === 'sold-entries' ? index : undefined
        })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch your action using dispatcher

actions.js:

```js
export const setEntries = (newEntries, soldEntries) => ({
    type: 'ENTRY_ACTION_NAME',
    newEntries,
    soldEntries
})
```

your component:

```js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setEntries} from './actions';

const YourComponent = ({setEntries}) => {
   /** your stuff here */
   useEffect(() => {
        var index;
        if (product_id === 'lime') index = 0
        if(product_id === 'travetine') index = 1
        // console.log(entry, index)
        setEntries(entry === 'new-entries' ? index : undefined,entry === 'sold-entries' ? index : undefined);
    }, []);
/**  rest of your stuff here */
}

export default connect(state => ({
  // state to props mappings here
}), dispatch => ({
  setEntries: (newEntries, soldEntries) => dispatch(setEntries(newEntries, soldEntries))
}))(YourComponent);
```

and then somewhere in your reducer handle 'ENTRY_ACTION_NAME' action.

Comment: basically the issue was I wasn't passing the action as a prop after importing it in the file, big thanks for the insight +1